# Rubber Deployment: complete_passenger_mysql setup cannot connect to AWS instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssh, rubber

I was following the railcast tutorial, attempting to test out deployment with Rubber. Managed to survive from the Duplicated rules error, creating instance error, etc but I was finally stopped by the infinite connection loop:

```
 ** Instance running, fetching hostname/ip data
Trying to enable root login
  * 2014-01-16 15:36:41 executing `rubber:_ensure_key_file_present'
  * 2014-01-16 15:36:41 executing `rubber:_allow_root_ssh'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'mkdir -p /root/.ssh && cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'"
    servers: ["---.---.---.---"]
 ** Can't connect as user ubuntu to ---.---.---.---, assuming root allowed
  * 2014-01-16 15:36:44 executing `rubber:_direct_connection_---.---.---.---_673'
  * executing "echo"
    servers: ["---.---.---.---"]
 ** Failed to connect to ---.---.---.---, retrying
  * 2014-01-16 15:36:48 executing `rubber:_direct_connection_---.---.---.---_673'
  * executing "echo"
    servers: ["---.---.---.---"]
 ** Failed to connect to ---.---.---.---, retrying
  * 2014-01-16 15:36:53 executing `rubber:_direct_connection_---.---.---.---_673'
  * executing "echo"
    servers: ["---.---.---.---"]
```

- The IP is masked...

I have tried a lot of different things:

- Manually connect to new instance with ssh and the key
- Double check the rubber.yml to see if the key path is correct
- Run the cap command in -v
- Check if the instance I defined is the same as the default ami type

They all seems ok so I think there must be something with the command used for rubber to connect and run the "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'mkdir -p /root/.ssh && cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/'". However there's no where I can see what Rubber was talking to my instance. I tried to get into the source code but it lead me to no where too.

I have done quite a number of googling and it seems like it is quite a common error but no real solution to this. Can anyone suggest what's likely to be the problem? Thank you.

UPDATE:

Some more thoughts: it is writing `** Can't connect as user ubuntu to 54.200.63.202, assuming root allowed`. So did rubber tried to ssh directly to root user? If so that may explain why. Are there anyway to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out why. It was a typo in my keyname.. I found this out by slowly regenerating the key_file string in console step by step. It is helpful to debug this key_path issues. Hope it may help someone!